# Slice theorem for proper groupoids

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology, principal-bundles, groupoids

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff (second countable) groupoid with Hausdorff (second countable) unit space $X$.
Assume $G$ is étale, i.e., the source and range maps of $G$ are local homeomorphisms. 
We say that $G$ is *proper* if the map $(s,r)\colon G \to X\times X$ is proper, i.e., the preimage of a compact subset is compact.

I think the following theorem is true, but I can't find a proof. I'd greatly appreciate any pointer.

> if $G$ is proper then each $x\in X$ admits an open neighborhood $U\subseteq X$ equipped with an action of $G_x^x$ (the automorphisms group at $x$) such that the restriction $G|_U$ is isomorphic to the action groupoid $U\rtimes G_x^x$ and the map (whenever it is defined)
>   $$ G\times_{G_x^x}U \to X$$
>   sending $[g,x]$ to $gx$ is a $G$-equivariant homeomorphism onto an open neighborhood of (the orbit of) $x\in X$.

**EDIT**: I would be interested to know if anything is known in the non-Lie non-étale case. When $G$ is a locally compact group (acting properly), a result of Abels says that $X$ is locally compactly induced, but the compact subgroup cannot (in general) be chosen to be a stabilizer. By analogy, for a locally compact proper groupoid $G$ it seems reasonable to prove that

> $G$ is locally Morita equivalent to an action groupoid by a compact group. More precisely, $X$ can be covered by opens $V$ which such that $G|_V$ is Morita equivalent to $U\rtimes H$ for $H$ a compact group acting on a subset $U\subseteq V$. Note that $U$ (the slice) need not be open.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303183/proper-and-etale-groupoid-is-locally-a-translation-groupoid ???

Comment: WHat does Principal bundles tag has anything to do with this question?

Comment: Thanks for your link. I somehow missed it. I'll think about it for a bit because it doesn't directly answer my question (or at least I don't see it yet). When the action is free, the theorem should say that you get a principal bundle, moreover the local model will always involve a principal bundle of some sort. That's why I used that tag.

Comment: May be you should specify what principal bundle you are looking for...

Comment: I'm not looking for a principal bundle. I am just saying that people interested in principal bundles might have something to say on this problem.

Comment: Perhaps the literature on orbispaces will have some hints...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the result suggested by Praphulla Koushik [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303183/proper-and-etale-groupoid-is-locally-a-translation-groupoid) is enough in the étale case.
Indeed, the image of the map in my question can be rewritten as the image of $$r\colon s^{-1}(U)\to X.$$ 
Since $r$ is a local homeomorphism, its image is open and obviously $G$-invariant. It is easy to see that by modding out $G|_U$ we get a bijection.